# Google Reader editing API Authentication problem

Tags: java, api, authentication, editing, google-reader

I have problem with authentication GReader editing API.  I can do the HTTPS (https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin) for authentication and google is returning three tokens (SID, LSID, AUTH), but no HSID.

When I try add a new feed http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/quickadd?ck=1290452912454&client=scroll with POST data T=djj72HsnLS8293&quickadd=blog.martindoms.com/feed/ without HSID in Cookie, is response status code 401. With SID and HSID in Cookie everything works properly.

What is and where can I find this HSID string?

Thaks for your answers.

My code:

```
public void addNewFeed() throws IOException {
        HttpPost requestPost = new HttpPost("http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription/quickadd?ck=1290452912454&client=scroll");
        getSid();          
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        requestPost.addHeader("Cookie", "SID=" + _sid + "; HSID=" + _hsid);
        try {
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("T", _token));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quickadd", "blog.martindoms.com/feed/"));
            requestPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(requestPost);

            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line + "\n");
            }
            System.out.println(str.toString());
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you might be using old info as a reference.  Google switched to using auth now.

You'll need to replace getSid() with a getAuth() function.

Then this line

```
requestPost.addHeader("Cookie", "SID=" + _sid + "; HSID=" + _hsid);
```

should now be this

```
requestPost.addHeader("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + _auth);
```